# How to speed up current query with index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, azure-sql-database

I'm using a v12 server in Azure SQL Database, and I have the following table:

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AudienceNiches](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WebsiteId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [VisitorId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [VisitDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Interest] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Gender] [float] NULL,
    [AgeFrom18To24] [float] NULL,
    [AgeFrom25To34] [float] NULL,
    [AgeFrom45To54] [float] NULL,
    [AgeFrom55To64] [float] NULL,
    [AgeFrom65Plus] [float] NULL,
    [AgeFrom35To44] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AudienceNiches] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)`

I'm executing this query: (UPDATED QUERY)

```
`select  a.interest, count(interest) from (
select visitorid, interest
from audienceNiches
WHERE WebsiteId = @websiteid
AND VisitDate >= @startdate
AND VisitDate <= @enddate
group by visitorid, interest) as a
group by a.interest`
```

And I have the following indexs (all ASC):

`idx_WebsiteId_VisitDate_VisitorId
idx_WebsiteId_VisitDate
idx_VisitorId
idx_Interest`

The problem is that my query return 18K rows aproximaly and takes 5 seconds, the whole table has 8.8M records, and if I expand a little the data the time increases a lot, so, what would be the best index to this query? What I'm missing?

Comment: What do you expect the resulting data to look like? I'm not sure how the aggregate functions do much if you're grouping by VisitorID.

Comment: I updated the query so something more simple can be achieved, I want per interest the total number of visitors uniques

Comment: Is WebsiteId a primary key?? I see you're filtering the WebsiteId by adding WebsiteId = @websiteid

Comment: nops, websiteid is a foreign key.

Comment: The service name is "Azure SQL Database"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best index for this query is a composite index on these columns, in this order:

- WebsiteId
- VisitDate
- Interest
- VisitorId

This allows the query to be completely answered from the index.  SqlServer can range scan on (`WebsiteId`, `VisitDate`) and then exclude null `Interest` and finally count distinct `VisitorIds` all from the index.  The indexes entries will be in the correct order to allow these operations to occur efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware about composite index, I'm assuming that you were talking about the INCLUDE() option when creating the index, so I put Interest and VisitorId in the include and websiteid and visitdate in the ON clause! That make the trick!

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult for me to write SQL without having the data to test against, but see if this gives the results you're looking for with a better execution time.

```
SELECT interest, count(distinct visitorid)
FROM audienceNiches
WHERE WebsiteId = @websiteid
AND VisitDate between @startdate and @enddate
AND interest is not null 
GROUP BY interest
```

Comment: Because `Interest` can be null, this may return a different answer.

Comment: Added a null check to the interest column.  Based on his revised query, I don't think he's interested in visitors who didn't have an interest.

Comment: the performance of this actualy takes a lot more time to execute, seems that using group by is more effective, not sure yet

Answer (score 1):

Indexes can require an almost infinite amount of understanding, but in your case I think you would see good performance gains by indexing the WebsiteId and VisitDate as separate indexes.

It's important though to make sure your indexes are in good shape. You need to maintain them by keeping statistics up to date, and rebuilding your indexes periodically.

Lastly, you should examine the query plan when tuning query performance. SQL Server will tell you if it thinks it would benefit from a column (or columns) being indexed, and also alert you to other performance related issues.

Press Ctrl+L from within Management Studio and see what's going on with the query.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong.  The OP has a very good index for this query, the composite index on `(WebsiteId`, VisitDate, VisitorId)`, in that order.

Comment: For the purpose of the test, I'm creating the visitdate index separate, I will update when the index finish being created

Comment: Don't forget to run a query execution plan and see if it gives you any hints. Upon reflection it may run better as a composite index, but you should be guided by the query plan results (Ctrl + L). Post up a screenshot of you need help interpreting it.

Answer (score 1):

Your query could be written in this way, because in final result set you do not pull column visitorid from table audienceNiches, so  no need to write two different level of group by. Check with this query and let me know if still facing performance issue.

```
select  interest, count(interest)
from audienceNiches
WHERE WebsiteId = @websiteid
AND VisitDate >= @startdate
AND VisitDate <= @enddate
group by interest
```

Comment: but if I have a visitorid that has the same interest two times? i would get them duplicated in my count, this is because a user can have two different values of interest during his lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your updated query can be effectively reduced to this:

```
select an.Interest, count(an.Interest)
from dbo.AudienceNiches an
where an.WebsiteId = @WebSiteId
    and an.VisitDate between @startdate and @enddate
group by an.Interest;
```

Second, depending on the cardinality of your data, one of the following indices will provide the best possible performance:

```
create index IX_AudienceNiches_WebSiteId_VisitDate_Interest on dbo.AudienceNiches
(WebSiteId, VisitDate, Interest);
```

or

```
create index IX_AudienceNiches_VisitDate_WebSiteId_Interest on dbo.AudienceNiches
(VisitDate, WebSiteId, Interest);
```

As your data will grow, however, I think that eventually the latter one will become more efficient, on average.

P.S. Your table is severely denormalised in multiple aspects. I only hope you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks roger, i got a better performance now but the thing is that i can't have the pair interest <-> visitorid duplicated in my result.